# How to get image size (width vs height) from S3 w/o downloading it?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, python-imaging-library

How to get image size (width vs height) from S3 w/o downloading it?

With filesystem I am using `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_image_size(filepath):
    try:
        with Image.open(filepath) as image:
            return image.size
    except:
        return None
```

How to do the same with `boto3`?

Comment: You can't. Unless you store the information into S3 object meta data, otherwise you must download the file to check it out.

Comment: @mootmoot can't I download part of file only to feed it to PIL?

Comment: There is no reliable way to do that.  If you have many files, the best way to do this is create a little EC2 instance within the same region to do check and update the object meta. Another ways is using  Lambda.

Comment: For a [PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2.pdf) image, do a [ranged GET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-byte-range-fetches.html) of the first 24 bytes to get the PNG signature (to ensure it's a PNG) and then the width and height headers and values. Other image formats may also have width and height stored early in the file. Or store them in object metadata, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This, as of right now, is not supported with AWS S3. Here are a couple of ideas:

### **Including It In Metadata Upon Upload**

Through the console, you should be able to edit the metadata to include the size of the image. However, assuming you wanted to migrate your images without having to manual edit that data, you could import your data into an s3 bucket like so to also include the size of the image:

```
import boto3
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

def upload_images(directory: str, extensions: list, bucket: str) -> None:
    s3r = boto3.resource("s3")
    d = Path(directory)

    for extension in extensions:
        pathlist = d.glob(f"**/*{extension}")
        for path in pathlist:
            img = Image.open(path)
            w, h = img.size
            key = f"your/key/to/{path.name}"
            o = s3r.Object(bucket, key)
            o.put(Data=img.tobytes(),
                Metadata={"width": str(w), "height": str(h)},
                ContentType=Image.MIME[img.format])
```

### **Without Storing It On The File System**

I didn't want to store the file locally, but I didn't care if the image was loaded completely into memory, so:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import boto3
import botocore


def get_img(bucket: str, key: str):
    s3r = boto3.resource("s3")
    o = s3r.Object(bucket, key)
    try:
        o.load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError:
        print("Could not find image.")
        return None
    buffer = BytesIO()
    o.download_fileobj(buffer)
    img = Image.open(buffer)
    return img
```

and of course, since the above returns an image object, you can use the `size` attribute on it.

Comment: This downloads the entire file, right?

Comment: I only ask because it seems the question objective was to only download as much of the file as required to get its size.  Or not download any of it at all if possible.